# How to get the from..to offset from tcpdump output to use with iptables string match module

Tags: iptables, tcpdump, netfilter

I'm trying to get the 'from' and 'to' offset to use in my iptables rule with the string match module. Here is my output packet from the tcpdump tool:

```
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
05:49:49.631211 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.57625 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.13333: Flags [S],   seq 1036987151, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 770422252 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
0x0000:  4514 003c 9ee3 4000 3a06 9772 bca5 2e4d  E..<..@.:..r...M
0x0010:  b009 6f56 e119 2f4f 3dcf 2b0f 0000 0000  ..oV../O=.+.....
0x0020:  a002 7210 6e7e 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r.n~..........
0x0030:  2deb b5ec 0000 0000 0103 0307            -...........
```

The hex units i'm looking for their start-end position are :

```
bca5 2e4d b009 6f56
```

My aim is to get this iptables rule to work properly:

```
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -m string --from xx --to yy --algo bm --hex-string "|bca52e4db0096f56|" -j DROP
```

By the way my rule is already working fine without using the from-to offset.

Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your original question, you may use :

```
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -m string --from 12 --to 20 --algo bm --hex-string "|bca52e4db0096f56|" -j DROP
```

**But, there is more to get the final answer as you want to improve the efficiency of iptables by adding these two options.**

What I found is a little disappointing, it seems that `--to` option doesn't work.

I paste the original related content of `man iptables` in `CentOS release 6.5 (Final)`:

```
--from offset
Set the offset from which it starts looking for any matching. If not passed, default is 0.
--to offset
Set the offset from which it starts looking for any matching. If not passed, default is the packet size.
```

As you see, the description of option `--to` is wrong, so is the result of my experiment use `--to` option. However, `--from` option works fine as the description.

The final answer is that the part of the bad packet represents **src ip and dest ip** of ip protocol, so you may use (I don't use the ip in your packet content in your question for your privacy issue, but the ip is already exposed, so maybe you can change your question) :

```
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -s xx.xx.xx.xx -d xx.xx.xx.xx -j DROP
```

**Update, use module u32:**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -m u32 --u32 "12=0xbca52e4d && 16=0xb0096f56" -j DROP
```

Comment: The 1st suggestion to my original question does not work for me. I have a doubt about the exact method to calculate the from-to position.The HEX representation of TCPDUMP is it really the internal representation of the captured packets. The attacker use different sources to send the packets, so this rule `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -s xx.xx.xx.xx -d xx.xx.xx.xx -j DROP` will not help me a lot. After a period of time the source ip is taked by a nother one who is not attacking me but still neutralized by my iptables rules which is a situation that i'm doing my best to avoid.

Comment: I'm a little confused that what is the constant part of packets you want to filter. As what you showed in the question, the content begins at offset 12 and ends at offset 20, is constant and the value is "bca52e4db0096f56", which is the content of src ip and dest ip in the protocol.  What do you mean by 'does not work", the 1st suggestion could not capture any packets ? Or even after you change the value of 'from'/'to' to an invalid value, it still capture packets.

Comment: I tried to edit my previous comment, sorry you are right, my problem is that the "to" offset is not working. As you said in your previous comment the "from" work like a charme.if i start from 13 no packet captured work only with 12 as start position, but any value assigned to "to" the packet still captured even with --to 13.Any solution ?

Comment: Base on what I can get now, it seems a bug of iptables. There are two possible solution: 1. find if there is some filter syntax in iptables like "tcp[32:4]=0xxxxxxx" in tcpdump; 2. fix the bug of iptables ourselves or post an issue to netfilter.

Comment: I agree with you, i tried to get arround this issue without success, as i'm not a C programmer i will not manage to fix the bug by myself, if you can do that it will be a cool solution, or posting an issue to netfilter regarding this issue as a last alternative. I heared about a module named u32 it seems that it can do more than the string module with effeciency.Any idea ? I already tried to use it without success the doc is little bit hard to understand and decode.

Comment: I think u32 is enough, I will try and update the answer later.

Comment: I'm getting confused reading again your previous comment when you said "the content begins at offset 12 and ends at offset 20, is constant and the value is "bca52e4db0096f56", which is the content of src ip and dest ip in the protocol." The source address changes all the time, why this part stay constant even it contains the src address which not the same all the time? Please clarify if possible. I appreciate a lot your help and comments, you are pushing me to digg more to understand all the related things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114527/discussion-between-sel-fish-and-user3072470).

Comment: Sometimes words are not enough to thank a person who share his precious time and experience with you to sort a problem you are facing.1 000 000 thanks @sel-fish, even i believe that you are not a sel-fish. :). I left a nother message for you in the discussion board please read it when you have a time.

Comment: I'm flattered @user3072470, thank you for bringing me the question.